# javascript mixing numbers and strings in a single statement

Tags: javascript, types

I want to change a number to a string like this:

```
var i = slides.length*100;
i += '%';
el.style.height = i;
```

But I see that I could also do it all in one statement:

```
el.style.height = slides.length*100 + '%';
```

Is it ok to mix numbers and strings in a single statement like this? or should I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out mixing strings and numbers in this way is fine provided you understand operator precedence:

for example:

```
3 * 100 + '%'; -> String = '300%'
3 + 100 + '%'; -> String = '103%'
'%' + 100 + 3; -> String = '%1003'
'%'+(100 + 3); -> String = '%103'
3 + 100 * '%'; -> Number = NaN
```

Hope that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

In general you can concatenate many methods together to join them in to a single argument. If you're new the general rule is if your test works in the big four rendering engines (Gecko/Firefox, Presto/Opera, Trident/Internet Explorer and WebKit (Safari and the Chrome fork) then generally either that is the intended behavior or you ended up getting really lucky, almost always the first though. Just keep on experimenting and keep a few small things in mind with JavaScript...

JavaScript is NOT the DOM though it's VERY easy to confuse the two. The DOM is basically the representation of the (X)HTML code and methods such as getElementById are part of the DOM specification and not Ecmascript.

Don't use innerHTML, it doesn't properly register the DOM.

Don't use frameworks, they are horribly written (and use innerHTML), are horribly slow compared to native rendering and are not application compatible (and most people don't know the difference between script and application level).

Use alert(typeof my_variable); to determine the TYPE of an object.

Remember that there are no arrays in JavaScript, just objects that everyone like to refer to as arrays.

There are no dumb questions, just bad ones; I voted you back up, there can be a lot of people with bad attitudes on here, ignore them. Your question was short, concise and not open to a lot of subjectivity (like code you didn't post or refer to).